# Webpack - Bundling legacy files that depend on each other globals

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working with a legacy project and I try to convert it to a modern webpack project, with minimum changes to the original legacy files.

The problem is that many of these legacy files rely on each other's globals, e.g:

*legacy1.js*

```
console.log("Legacy1");
function globalMess() {
  console.log("I am doing global mess!")
}
```

*legacy2.js*

```
console.log("Legacy2");
globalMess();%
```

The ideas solution would be one that:

1. Allows all the legacy files use each other globals without me searching for every global.
2. The globals would be only global to the legacy files, and not leak out to the real global scope.
3. Allow me to use Webpack's cache busting hash on the resulting legacy file. So that if I do I fix a bug in one the legacy files, the resulting file would have a new hash (e.g *legacy1.abc.js*).
4. Automatically add the resulting file to index.html usings something like **HtmlWebpackPlugin**.

## What I've considered so far

These are solutions I've considered:

**Solution 1**

Simply inject them manually into `index.html`, in the same order they appear in the original project. This solution would have no cache busting and would leak globals.

**Solution 2**

Using **ExposeLoader**/**ProvidePlugin**. Those require me know specify each and every global that each library exposes. This doesn't make sense to me as I have 20 legacy files and each exposes some random function and I don't really know which exposes what.

**Solution 3**

Using **webpack-raw-bundler**. It concats the files, pretty much like I wanted. However, it doesn't support cache busting via hash or automatically adding itself to index.html.

## Ideal solution

So what I imagine as an ideal solution would be a webpack plugin that globs all the legacy files, bundles them all as into a single file in its own function and produces a single file with a hash. That file will also get injected into the index.html using the logic of **HtmlWebpackPlugin**.

Its usage would look something like that:

```
new LegacyBundlePlugin({
  uglify: false,
  sourceMap: false,
  name: "legacy",
  fileName: "[name].[hash:8].js",
  filesToConcat: ["./legacy1.js", "./legacy2.js"],
}),
```

Which would produce the following:

```
(function () {

  console.log("Legacy1");
  function globalMess() {
    console.log("I am doing global mess!")
  }

  console.log("Legacy2");
  globalMess();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best solution I found is using **webpack-concat-plugin**.

It bundles everything to a single file, allows me to use cache busting and adds itself via **HtmlWebpackPlugin** to the resulting html.

The only thing it doesn't do is not-leaking to the global scope as it simply concats the provided files and doesn't put them into any scope.